# Uploading APK in play store by two different users and private keys

Tags: android

We are two developers working on same app. In my absence he will be uploading the app in the play store from different machine and location. When he tried to upload he's facing the private key's are different also with the same keystore file. How to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can't do that.
If the private keys don't match exactly, they are not the same app.

That is kinda the whole point of having the private key.  So no one can go and overwrite your app with one of their own.

You guys need to synch up, and get one private key that you can share.

Comment: Thanks for the answer . How to get private key and share to others.

Comment: Do you have the private key that was used when the app was first published?

Comment: I think so, how to get those private key whether it will be stored in any folder in MAC \

Comment: It's not a matter of "I think so."  If you do not have the original key, you cannot update the app.  It really is as simple as that.  No one, including Google Play, can provide that to you.  I advise that you make a new key, and share that file with your partner.  This, of course means, that you will have to create a whole new entry in Google Play.